# Refreshed Dev and Full sandboxes. Now no apex jobs are running. Data is not flowing from middleware to SFDC

Tags: integration, sandbox, refresh

After refreshed, I reset the password for the Integration profile. Updated the security token in the middleware. Still no data is coming into SFDC. No apex jobs are running.

Comment: We're going to need quite a bit more information than this to work with you to fix this...when you say Apex jobs, you mean that no scheduled jobs are running?

Answer (score 1):

Check your endpoints on the integration side. We've had our URL's change on us a couple of times after a refresh. They should be dynamic, but sometimes they aren't.